# Implement ESL in amazon connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, freeswitch, amazon-connect

In **Amazon connect**, I need to pass call flow to an external application via a socket and control the call from that application .

Something like **`ESL`** in `Freeswitch`: [Event Socket Library](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Event+Socket+Library)

For those who do not know what ESL is, it pass the call to a socket in external application and get command from that application like `Play`, `Disconnect`

And then all commands are available in `ESL` library in `Freeswitch`.

Does amazon connect have such ability?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can start connection using websockets

As per [AWS manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html) for the `Amazon Connect Participant Service`:

> Method `CreateParticipantConnection` creates the participant's connection. Note that ParticipantToken is used for invoking this API instead of ConnectionToken.
>
> The response URL for `WEBSOCKET` Type has a connect expiry timeout of 100s. Clients must manually connect to the returned websocket URL and subscribe to the desired topic.
>
> Upon websocket URL expiry, as specified in the response ConnectionExpiry parameter, clients need to call this API again to obtain a new websocket URL and perform the same steps as before.
>
> Request Syntax
>
> ``POST /participant/connection HTTP/1.1
> X-Amz-Bearer: `ParticipantToken`
> Content-type: application/json
>
> {
> "[Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html#connectparticipant-CreateParticipantConnection-request-Type)": [ "`string`" ]
> }``
>
> URI Request Parameters
>
> The request uses the following URI parameters.
>
> **[ParticipantToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html#API_CreateParticipantConnection_RequestSyntax)**
>
> This is a header parameter.
>
> The Participant Token as obtained from [StartChatContact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartChatContact.html) API response.
>
> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 1000.
>
> Required: Yes
>
> ### Request Body
>
> The request accepts the following data in JSON format.
>
> **[Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html#API_CreateParticipantConnection_RequestSyntax)**
>
> Type of connection information required.
>
> Type: Array of strings
>
> Array Members: Minimum number of 1 item.
>
> Valid Values: `WEBSOCKET | CONNECTION_CREDENTIALS`

## Sample `GO` code

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/connectparticipant/)

```
type CreateParticipantConnectionInput struct {

    // This is a header parameter.
    //
    // The Participant Token as obtained from StartChatContact (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartChatContact.html)
    // API response.
    //
    // ParticipantToken is a required field
    ParticipantToken *string `location:"header" locationName:"X-Amz-Bearer" min:"1" type:"string" required:"true"`

    // Type of connection information required.
    //
    // Type is a required field
    Type []*string `min:"1" type:"list" required:"true"`
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
type CreateParticipantConnectionOutput struct {

    // Creates the participant's connection credentials. The authentication token
    // associated with the participant's connection.
    ConnectionCredentials *ConnectionCredentials `type:"structure"`

    // Creates the participant's websocket connection.
    Websocket *Websocket `type:"structure"`
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}


var params CreateParticipantConnectionInput;
mySession := session.Must(session.NewSession())

// Create a ConnectParticipant client from just a session.
client := connectparticipant.New(mySession)

// Create a ConnectParticipant client with additional configuration
client := connectparticipant.New(mySession, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-west-2"))

params.ParticipantToken := getToken();// The Participant Token as obtained from StartChatContact (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartChatContact.html) 
req, resp := client.CreateParticipantConnection(params);

err := req.Send()
if err == nil { // resp is now filled
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

## ESL alternative

As for your question:

> It pass the call to a socket in external application and get command from that application like `Play`, `Disconnect`
> And then all commands are available in `ESL` library in `Freeswitch`

AWS are unlikely to plan this functionality.

Comment: it seems you have a good knowledge on Amazon Connect . is it possible to develop something like plugin and mount in contacts flows ?